# In CSS, When I scroll the scroll bar, the background-color of <li> disappeared

Tags: html, css

HTML code like this:

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li class='a'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
        <li class='b'>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS code like this:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll
}

.a {
    background-color: red;
}

.b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

When I scroll the scroll bar, I see that the background color is only applied to the original unscrolled region. How can I solve this problem.

[My Code is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/VMZ87/)

---

**EDIT**

**[Another example showing my problem clearly.](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/VMZ87/3/)**

**I have a second problem now: the second line disappeared...why**

Comment: and I used to think that default display setting for `<li>` is inline, but it's list-item. +1

Comment: there are a couple solutions here you might want to check all the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the list items you need to set the `display` property to `inline-block` and set the `min-width` property to 100%. Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMZ87/5/), and see below:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;   
}

li {
    min-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-row; /* or inline-block */   
}

.a, .c, .e, .g {
    background-color: red;
}

.b, .d, .f {
    background-color: blue;
}​
```

**EDIT**

To make all of the `li` elements the width of the longest `li`, use `display: table-row`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMZ87/10/) for a demonstration.

```
li {
    min-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-row;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/VMZ87/3/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/VMZ87/7/).

Comment: Thank you, as for the first, what can I do if I want all the `li`s have the same width of their background-color ( to the max of the `li`s width ) ? can you understand me?

Comment: Updated my answer. Instead of `display: inline-block` use `display: table-row`. That should make all `li` elements the same width.

Comment: why as soon as I use `display: table-row`, `list-style-type` will not work?

Answer (score 1):

The long unbreakable text (aaaaaaaa.....) is causing the text to extrude out of the `div` which you've specified to have a width of 400px. If you want to maintain the width you can stop the text from extruding by applying this rule

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/v6TVg/

[Support is good for this rule](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap)

Comment: Doesn't this just drop the text to the next line so it doesn't scroll? I thought OP wanted the list to scroll...

Comment: Thank you, but I just want it can scroll. [This expmale](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/VMZ87/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use word-wrap:break-word; because the word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with this code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzubv/)

What I have done here is introduce an inner div

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="in">
```

and set its CSS like this

```
#in {
    width:500px;
}
```

Note that 500px is the maximum width in the `<li>` item.

By the way this is the standard behavior how it works. If you ever worked with code plugins in Wordpress. They behave in exact same way. If you scroll to the right, the scrolled text has no background.

Answer (score -1):

You can overcome this problem by defining your lists as `inline`

```
li { display: inline; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VMZ87/1/)

Comment: This fundamentally changes the behavior of the LI and should not be used unless the new behavior is desired, which the OP has not indicated.

Comment: @Umbrella, Since when was the behavior of a `li` not to be inline?

Comment: The default for `li` is {display:list-item}, changing that to `inline` causes them to flow like normal text, not usually desirable.

Comment: @Umbrella, And your point, is `No, LI's can't be inline, Its just wrong` or you have some facts to back this up.

Comment: It's not "wrong" in general, just here because it just changes their rendering in a way the OP is not requesting.  It does not give the OP the final result they seek.  It may be fine in this trivial example, but when they try it in their real document, it will likely cause other problems.

Comment: @Umbrella, I only agree with your last comment. Remaining is bogus (sorry)