# Why can I not use display:table-row with list-style-type:decimal?

Tags: html, css

Why I cannot use `display:table-row;` with `list-style-type:decimal;` ?

my CSS file:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}

li {
    background-color: red;
    display: table-row;
}
```

my HTML file:

```
<ol>
    <li>This is the first.</li>
    <li>This is the second.</li>
</ol>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unimous/XMrbu/10/)

Goal: I just want to display the numbers leading each line, with all `<li>` as long as the longest item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `list-style-type` only works with `display:list-item`. :/

Per [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type):

> `list-style-type`
>     **Applies to:** elements with `display: list-item`

---

**Edit** Based on new information in your comments, you can do this on modern browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/XMrbu/12/

```css
ol {
   list-style-type:none;        
   counter-reset: sectioncounter;
}                      
li { display:table-row }
li:before {
   content: counter(sectioncounter) ":";
   counter-increment: sectioncounter;
   display:inline-block; width:2em; text-align:right;
   position:relative; left:-2.5em; margin-right:-2em;
}​
```

Or what about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/XMrbu/14/

```css
ol {
   display:inline-block;
   list-style-type:decimal;
   background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

If you make the `ol` be `display:inline-block` (or `float` it) it will automatically collapse to the width of the longest item inside. You can then style the `ol` or `li` as you like to that width.

Comment: Oh, you mean, I can't use `list-style-type` with `display:table-row`? but I want all the `<li>`s have the same width and leaded by a number. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [this is my origin problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127602/in-css-when-i-scroll-the-scroll-bar-the-background-color-of-li-disappeared) @BoltClock'saUnicorn

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I just want all the `<li>`s have the same width as the longest `<li>`, but I don't know the exact width of the longest.

Comment: @UniMouS I'm going the extra mile for that accept mark; see my edits and if either will work for you? :)